# Return total count of list of words in a string python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I know the following function will simply return a count of a word in a sentence. I'm trying to loop through a `df['col']` using a list of words. I currently have my function set up to loop over each row. But I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid using a nested loop.

```
def count_occurrences(word, sentence):
    return sentence.lower().split().count(word)
```

For example, say my column is as below. I want to count how many times the words in the following list occurs in each sentence e.g.

```
list_of_words = ['green','apple']

ind |   df['col']
------------------------------------------
1.  |  'green apple red apple blue apple'
2.  |  'green apple green apple green apple'
```

Output:

```
[4,6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```py
>>> df
                                   col
0     green apple red apple blue apple
1  green apple green apple green apple
>>>
>>> df.col.str.count('|'.join(list_of_words)).tolist()
[4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! Do you know if this can be changed to ignore cap? So I don't have to add 'Green' and 'green' to the list? Also, in my use case, I noticed one of my words 'IT' was counted because it appeared in 'HIT', can I add a space condition?

Comment: You can pass flags to `str.count` (you need to `import re`). For example, `df.col.str.count('|'.join(list_of_words), re.I).tolist()` will return `[4, 6]` if I change the 2nd row to `green apple green apple Green apple`, but w/o the flag it will give you `[4, 5]`.

Comment: Thanks for answering everything. Appreciate the help!

Comment: For the `IT` vs `HIT` issue you can try @BENY's answer; that is, construct your regex in a way so that you look for complete words, `\b` is for word boundaries (check `re`'s docs)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df_counts = df["col"].str.split().explode().value_counts()
df_counts[list_of_words]
```

output:

```
green    4
apple    6
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

This may be a more useful output form than a list of counts.  Or, if you just want the list:

```
df_counts[list_of_words].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better adding `/b` in case you have `pineapple`

```
df['cnt'] = df['col'].str.count(r'/b|/b'.join(list_of_words))
```